# Spring Java Configuration: overridden @Bean method invoked before autowiring

Tags: spring, inheritance, autowired, spring-java-config

I have `RepositoryConfig` extending `Neo4jConfiguration`. The latter sets up a number of beans with @Bean annotated methods. `RepositoryConfig`overrides `getGraphDatabaseService` which is invoked before any fields in `RepositoryConfig` are autowired. That is a problem since I want to use the autowired stuff inside the `getGraphDatabaseService`method.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "neo4j")
public class RepositoryProperties {
   [...]
}

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.foo.bar")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RepositoryProperties.class)
public class RepositoryConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
   @Autowired
   private RepositoryProperties properties;

   @Override
   @Bean(name = "graphDatabaseService", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
   public GraphDatabaseService getGraphDatabaseService() {
      [...] // properties is 'null' at this point
   }

   @PostContstruct
   public void foo() {
      [...] // properties is initiated OK here
   }
}
```

Why is `getGraphDatabaseService`being called before autowiring is complete? I guess it has to do with the inheritance... If I remove the inheritance then autowiring is complete at the time `getGraphDatabaseService`is called. I've also tried annotating the method with @DependsOn, with no luck.

Any ideas is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen this too occasionally.  I think there are two workarounds.

Option 1. Autowire the bean definition

```
@Override    
@Bean(name = "graphDatabaseService", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
@Autowired
public GraphDatabaseService getGraphDatabaseService() {
  [...] // properties is 'null' at this point
}
```

Option 2. Inject the bean

```
@Override    
@Bean(name = "graphDatabaseService", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService getGraphDatabaseService(@Autowired RepositoryProperties properties) {
   // can probably delete the Config member with this approach
  [...] // properties is 'null' at this point
}
```